Wouldn't the ban of TikTok violate freedom of speech?
My assumption has always been that government mandated blockage of any website is not allowed in the US as it was an "abridging the freedom of speech".
Is the banning of websites within the US legally different than the banning of specific applications from an app store? Can the US government ban the accessing of certain websites?

First Amendment of the US Constitution:

Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.


I have been made aware that more generalized questions may reflect the true nature of this Legality.

On the accessing of websites: Can the United States Government ban access to certain websites/services?

On the publication of software: Can the federal government prohibit the publication of software it does not like?

On the distribution of software: Is the distribution of software protected under free speech? (in the United States)


I think this question is still good to keep up as it has an answer. However, I feel like these do better reflect the overall question.

This question is similar to: Can the federal government prohibit the publication of software it does not like?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@littleadv I think you are correct. This is somewhat to a specific instance but my question can be asked better. I have read "I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?" and think it may be best to leave this one up as it is answered but post a secondary question.

This question can also broken up better into three different questions. I will work on ensuring those are sent instead.

Your title says "the ban of TikTok" but your body talks about "banning of websites". The ban you are talking about does not ban any websites. The ban you are talking about does not prevent the TikTok website from continuing to be used inside the US, nor does it prevent the TikTok app from continuing to be used inside the US if you have it.



My assumption has always been that government mandated blockage of any website is not allowed in the US as it was an "abridging the freedom of speech". << Would you consider hosting child pornography as freedom of speech?



You're reading media articles that say "ban of TikTok" but that has been dumbed-down for you by the media wags you have chosen to trust.  What's actually happening is quite different, and you need to deep-dive that if you want to know.

The problem is that many Americans take the First Amendment to mean "I can say whatever I want". That is not true, and never has been. Incitement, defamation, "fighting words" etc. aren't covered by the First Amendment, nor should they be. Free Speech means a right to voice your displeasure with e.g. the government. The rest is wishful thinking by... let's say, "certain types". And TikTok isn't "the press" either, it's a piece of software.

Well, China also has "freedom of speech" in its constitution, yet it has banned countless websites. I suppose that the US could "justify" its banning of TikTok in a similar way the Chinese lawmakers justify banning a website after a website, in spite of the constitution protecting free speech. "Freedom of speech" essentially means you cannot get in jail for saying something (in praxis, it doesn't even mean that), not that the government will not block a website.

In the case of a proposed TikTok ban (at least by the U.S., other country's reasons may vary), the ban is not primarily directed at the content provided by the TikTok users. Indeed, generally, proposed TikTok bans allow for the sale of the platform to a U.S. based third-party, with the new owners providing essentially the same online experience with the same content as TikTok does today.
The primary concern is that the particular firm that owns and runs TikTok is engaged in illegal conduct, basically, espionage, for a foreign country (i.e. the People's Republic of China), using the TikTok app for improper means. Basically, the TikTok app is a form of spyware.
I personally have no idea if these allegations are really true. But legislative action to ban it is based upon a legislative judgment that these allegations are true and pose a threat to national security.
This certainly could be happening. For example, the mobile phone game "Angry Birds" was used for improper purposes, not by the firm that created it, but because a hacker was able to steal geolocation data and other personal information about huge numbers of people, from that firm without its knowledge. This was made possible as a result of lax cyber security by a firm that was, after all, not engaged in an activity we associate with the need for high security (i.e. running a mobile game app). Doing it on purpose with the permission of the firm owning/running the app would be easier.
Banning a firm for improper or illegal practices is very different from a ban based upon the content that is exchanged on a platform, which in all likelihood would violate the First Amendment.

I'm not an expert user on this stack, so take with a grain of salt: Would it improve this answer to include why/how/when such uses are considered to be speech that is not protected? Clearly there must be national security exceptions to the first amendment because we have security clearances and prosecution for espionage, etc. It seems to me that's at the (legal) heart of this question: the fact that not 100% of speech is protected and specifically speech that threatens national security is not protected. Or is it not about speech at all but commerce?

@ToddWilcox No, because the tiktok ban isn't about speech but commerce.

@Trish Did you mean to write, "Yes, the TikTok ban is about commerce, not speech," as an answer to my last question? Either way, maybe this answer could be improved by clarifying that. The first amendment doesn't prohibit regulation of commerce.

@ToddWilcox "Would it improve this answer to include why/how/when such uses are considered to be speech that is not protected?" There are full semester law school courses on that topic.

@ToddWilcox the No is on the basic premise, that this needs to be extended. It's clear enough: this all is not about speech

"The primary concern is that the particular firm that owns and runs TikTok is engaged in illegal conduct," but several lawmakers have said that TikTok should be banned because of the way it presents content to users (calling it "addictive", saying it fails to moderate "harmful" content or misinformation, etc.), i.e. because of things which are protected by the First Amendment. It seems like ByteDance will argue that the national security justification is a pretext, particularly since (AFAIK) it still remains legal for American-owned companies to sell equivalent data to Chinese companies.

@kaya3 A legitimate justification, like illegal conduct that threatens national security, can have side effects. But, given that most of the proposals allow a U.S. firm to take over the same platform, it is hard to see how that would be content regulating. Some bills may indeed by content oriented (and there are some kinds of conduct that can be restricted). But the bulk of folks seeking to ban TikTok don't seem to havee that as their motivation. The fact that a few people voting for it have an impermissible motive doesn't render the law invalid.

Also to point out that if "you can express yourself on it" inherently leads to protections regarding freedom of speech, it would become a laughably easy loophole to get away with pretty much anything. The Pirate Bay has a comment section, should its use be protected by the First Amendment? What about any forums that deal in illegal content, should we protect it because people also communicate on it? The underlying assertion of the question would be an incredibly easy to exploit loophole if it were correct.

@kaya3: Just because two separate arguments are made as to why something should be banned, that does not mean that any subsequent ban therefore agrees that both arguments are equally the reason for the ban.

@Flater under that argument, it would be unconstitutional to ban international media from targeting the US... which is illegal under the Smith-Mundt Act.

@Flater I don't assert that a court would necessarily consider both justifications, I'm only pointing out that ByteDance will make this argument, and I think that argument needs to be engaged with (perhaps to explain why it will definitely not prevail in court) in order to give a complete answer to this question. It might be true that a court would normally ignore the "TikTok promotes harmful speech" rationale (problematic under 1A) when an alternative rationale is valid and sufficient to uphold the law. But the alternative rationale isn't obviously valid given that whichever US company ...

... ends up buying TikTok, would probably still be legally allowed to sell the same or equivalent data to Chinese-owned companies. Will a court necessarily agree that this law is justified by its stopping Americans' personal data getting into the hands of Chinese companies, when (AFAICT) the law might not actually do that?

@kaya3 Laws are allowed to be stupid or flawed and still constitutional.

Who's speaking? Not Tiktok.
Congress may not make a law that bans protected speech, but the proposed law is not about the speech of Tiktok, it's all about commerce: it just bans a company from operating in the US while owned by a Chinese company. That is fully legal and precedented. Did you know the FCC Broadcast Ownership rules made it illegal to own a newspaper and a TV station for a long time? And that until 2013, foreign media couldn't make their normal broadcast availeable to the US legally under the Smith-Mundt Act, and that it is still illegal for a foreign media to focus all its broadcasts at the US?
Those are not restrictions of speech, they are restrictions on commerce and ownership. Banning Tiktok in the US while under Chinese ownership is just a new commercial law, not one that impacts or implicates Tiktok's speech.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here.

Note that the D.C. Circuit has decided this question. The court concludes that the law is a restriction on TikTok's speech -- albeit a permissible one. TikTok Inc. v. Garland, No. 24-1113, 26 (D.C. Cir. Dec. 6, 2024) (“The Act plainly singles out that expressive activity by indirectly subjecting TikTok - and so far, only TikTok - to the divestiture requirement.”).
